# Getting 'no such file or directory' when trying to read json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs

I'm trying to read from a json file but I'm getting an error for some reason. I think I'm doing everything right but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Which directory context are you running the code from?

Comment: Are you sure, this is the only place you are trying to read this file? Check or post the full error stack as to which line this error is being thrown to.

Comment: in Node.js you can `require` json files: `const wordBank = require('./wordBank.json');`

Comment: @ggorlen - That is why I used the image to show that they are in fact being ran from the same directory.

Comment: @ShivamSood Yes. It's a little cut off in the image but in the error stack it says that the error is being thrown from `wordBank.js:4:21`

Comment: @FredStark - I was thinking that was the case but that also gave me issues. But I'm checking it now and the direct import seems to work just fine.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure `fs` uses the `CWD` of the app, ie the location of it's main js file. So you would need `fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/wordBank.json')`

Comment: @FredStark is correct, you need to use `__dirname`, if the .js file from where you are starting your server is different (as we can see it is) to where you are trying to access the `wordBank.js` file. you need to concatenate `__dirname`.

Comment: @FredStark - Thanks. I was able to get the direct import working so I'll just go with that, but I'll keep that in mind for next time I'm working with fs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because `fs` will try to read files relative to the location of the main module (ie the file passed to node when you run your app: `node server.js`)

In order to have `fs` read a file relative to the current module, use the `__dirname` variable:

```
fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/wordBank.json')
```

Or, since you're trying to read JSON, you can `require` it like a module:

```
const wordBank = require('./wordBank.json');
```

`require` is always relative to the current module.